# “The text is about” in German

Tags: english-to-german, phrase-request

Do you say

> Der Text, den ich gelesen habe, handelt sich um einen türkischen Jungen, der Metin heißt.

*Handelt sich um* here means *is about,* doesn’t it?

Comment: Yes, "sich um etwas handeln" means "to be about something".

Answer (score 8):

No, the expression that you are looking for is [“von etwas handeln”](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/handeln_arbeiten_Handwerk#Bedeutung5b). You may be confusing this with [“sich um etwas handeln”](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/handeln_arbeiten_Handwerk#Bedeutung6a)

So your example should be corrected to:

> Der Text, den ich gelesen habe, handelt von einem türkischen Jungen...

“Sich handeln um” is a somewhat complicated construction with a completely different meaning. For example,

> Bei dem Text, den ich gelesen habe, handelt es sich um eine Kurzgeschichte.

would be a slightly convoluted way of saying

> Der Text, den ich gelesen habe, ist eine Kurzgeschichte.

As long as you do not want to say that the text is a boy, that construction is out of place here.

I have to say however, that I find some of the constructions in the Duden unusual (e.g. 5a and 6b). For example, according to 5a, you could also say

> Der Text, den ich gelesen habe, handelt um einen türkischen Jungen...

This is marked as “gehoben” (of a higher register) in Duden. I do not think that I have encountered this before, and I would advise you not to use it.

Comment: You should probably explain the difference.

Comment: Ja, ich würde gerne eine Erklärung sehen, weil ich "sich um etwas handeln" nachgeschlagen habe, und im Dict.cc steht "to be about"

Comment: @thekeyofgb then dict.cc is wrong.

Comment: @thekeyofgb, I have expanded my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing an exam, you could write something like "Der Text beschäftigt sich mit..." or "handelt von". This is more accurately a translation of "deals with".

Comment: Welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. We prefer longer answers here, that cover new aspects. Unfortunately your answer satisifies neither. Do take your time and do a [tour] of the site. If you have any questions, you might find the answer in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

In this case "handelt von" oder "dreht sich um" (revolves around) instead of "handelt sich um" is what you're looking for.

Comment: That's not what Jake asked. Also, your answer does not anything that Carsten Schultz didn't already write.